# mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN registered as tab rather then left click?

Tags: c++, event-handling, cursor, mouseevent, clr

Currently I'm trying to test out the clicking function through the following command

```
POINT cursorPos;
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
x = cursorPos.x;
y = cursorPos.y;
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Sleep(1000);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
cout << x << endl;
cout << y << endl;
```

However, when I run the application, the mouse does not register the x and y position, but when I press tab, it registered the x and y position. Is it because my mouse event has been registered to the tab button? Is there any way I can check? I am using C++ CLI Visual Studio 2013, thanks.

P.S : This is not a duplicate of my other question previously asked, because this question is related to mouse event handling rather then how to detect mouse clicking, thank you once again.

Cheers.

Comment: Should be a bit obvious, it doesn't "register" because you never passed them to mouse_event().  And beware the MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE option, should be turned on when x and y are absolute mouse coordinates instead of incremental.

Comment: Hi @Hans Passant, I did register them under the following:

private: System::Void panel1_MouseUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e). And how should you turn on the mouseevent absolute option?

Comment: Hmm, you are doing it wrong.  You only ever use mouse_event() to commandeer *another* program.   There is no point at all in emulating a mouse in your own program, just execute the code in your event handler directly.

Answer (score 1):

Found out from Han's Comment there is no point at all in emulating a mouse in your own program, I just executed the code in my event handler directly.